# absolute pos span disappering on second click of custom tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip, css-position, siblings

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nithin2e/6vKct/1/) code.

```
<li>one <a href="#" class="opt">delete</a>
        <div class="popup">
            <span class="tip"></span><a href="#" class="btn">deletebutton</a></div>
    </li>
```

code used to hide/show `div.popup`

```
$('.opt').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".popup").slideUp();
    $(this).closest("li").find(".popup").stop(true, false).slideToggle();
});
```

In click delete to open each `div.popup` but second click on the opened `div.popup` makes the `span.tip` to disappear. It does not appear anymore without refreshing page.

```
$(".popup").slideUp();
```

I found the problem is due to this code. I'm using this code to hide all other opened `.popup` on click of any delete anchor. I'm new to jQuery. Can anyone suggest an alternative method to hide `div.popup` siblings on click on any.

Thanks..

Comment: i thought of a working example is a better option. i will copy the same.

Comment: I can see the problem, but I don't know why it's happening. On first click, animations happen (as always) directly in the popup element's properties, reflected in Firebug as its 'style' attribute. Then they are cleared at the end of the animation. The second time of click, the same thing happens but they are NOT cleared, and the leftover styles are interfering with the way the tip is positioned. I don't have the fix but maybe that'll help someone.

Comment: yeah, added again. i accidentally approved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that during slideToggle jQuery is changing the popup element to have "overflow-x: hidden" thus the tip element, which is outside of the bounds stays hidden. I made an update to the jsfiddle so that it includes the tip element inside of the popup div. The animation looks a little different but I'm sure you can get it to look like it used to with a little finessing. http://jsfiddle.net/6vKct/5/ (I changed the tip to have a blue background so that it's more visible)

I changed

- the popup div top from "20px" to "15px"
- the tip div top from "-5px" to "0px"
- made the btn element relative positioned
- moved the btn element down by setting the top to "5px"
- moved the background color style from the entire popup div to just the btn

In effect I just made the popup div larger, moved it up and moved the tip inside of it.

Comment: awesome. thanks a lot. let me try now try the correction on the real code and let you know..

Answer (score 0):

add stop(true,true)

http://jsfiddle.net/6vKct/2/

Comment: Alas, this doesn't solve the issue. The .tip still doesn't come back when you make the delete popup reaappear.

Comment: still the same. on second click after first on the same link popup hides and if open again .tip does not appear.

Comment: what browser are you useing? it seams to be working fine for me/

Comment: try changing `$(".popup")` to `$(".popup:visible")`

Comment: Adam, in case it's not clear, it's the red thing on the right that appears. It has a little tip (in Chrome, it's just square) that points to the origin row. Click the 'delete' on the left and the red thing appears with tip. Click same one again to hide it. Click same one yet again and the red box appears but without the tip. Chrome on Win7 over here, BTW.